# Kivy popup call structure and bindings not making sence

Tags: python, kivy

Below is a working snippet example of a program that presents the user with menu popups to enter info.

The issues is getting the dismiss bindings working correctly. The program flow is currently:

- declare content with a return callback
- Load content into a popup object
- call the popup
- `__init__` is called and sets up something like `_keyboard` bindings
- User enters data and presses accept
- Return call back is called, the popup is no longer needed so we call `popup.dismiss()`
- popup closes and is it

The issue is if I do `_keyboard` binding in the `__init__` then when the popup closes I **MUST** call the unbind method or else the keyboard input is still calling the old popups functions!

Another thing I dislike is the return callback needing to call `self._popup.dismiss()`. I think it is much cleaner if the popup is completely self contained and completely reuseable. This is a numpad entry popup, it should bind the keyboard and unbind it by itself. The callback recieves an instance snapshot of the popup so the return data is easy to access. The popup itself should be the one to close itself as it knows for sure that the `returnCB()` was its final goal.

I have no idea how to implement this though. Binding on_dismiss inside of the `__init__` does nothing at all as `TouchGoToInput_dismiss` is never called. I also cant figure out how to get TouchGoToInput to close itself.

Another issue is if `ESC` is pressed the popup closes and once again the keyboard binding is messed up.

Can anyone lend me a hand understanding the call case structure?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup


Builder.load_string('''
<TouchGoToInput>:
    textInput:textInput
    cols: 1
    size: root.size
    pos: root.pos
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        size_hint_y:.25
        TextInput:
            size_hint_x:1.0
            font_size: self.height - 15
            padding_y: [self.height / 2.0 - (self.line_height / 2.0) * len(self._lines), 0]
            id:textInput
            disabled: True
    GridLayout:
        cols: 3
        Button:
            text: "1"
            on_release: root.addText("1")
        Button:
            text: "2"
            on_release: root.addText("2")
        Button:
            text: "3"
            on_release: root.addText("3")
        Button:
            text: "4"
            on_release: root.addText("4")
        Button:
            text: "5"
            on_release: root.addText("5")
        Button:
            text: "6"
            on_release: root.addText("6")
        Button:
            text: "7"
            on_release: root.addText("7")
        Button:
            text: "8"
            on_release: root.addText("8")
        Button:
            text: "9"
            on_release: root.addText("9")
        Button:
            text: "."
            on_release: root.addText(".")
        Button:
            text: "0"
            on_release: root.addText("0")
        Button:
            text: "Done"
            on_release: root.accept()
''')


class TouchGoToInput(GridLayout):

    returnCB = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TouchGoToInput, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.bind(on_dismiss=self.dismiss)
        print('TouchGoToInput.__init__')

    def dismiss(self):
        print('TouchGoToInput_dismiss')

    def addText(self, text):
        self.textInput.text = self.textInput.text + text

    def accept(self):
        print('TouchGoToInput.accept')
        self.returnCB(self)

    def __del__(self):
        print('TouchGoToInput.__del__')
        self.returnCB(self)


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.popupContent = TouchGoToInput(returnCB=self.gotoLinePopup)
        self._popup = Popup(title="GoTo...", content=self.popupContent,
                            size_hint=(0.9, 0.9))
        #self._popup.bind(on_dismiss=self.main_dismiss)
        return Factory.Button(text="press me", on_press=self._popup.open)

    def gotoLinePopup(self, instance):
        print('returnCB.text: ', instance.textInput.text)
        self._popup.dismiss()

    def main_dismiss(self, instance):
        print('main_dismiss')

TestApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

In the example, it demonstrates implementation of numpad using Popup widget with keyboard binding. It accepts input from Buttons, Keyboard, and NumPad.

[Popup » dismiss](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.popup.html#examples)

> By default, any click outside the popup will dismiss/close it. If you
>   don’t want that, you can set auto_dismiss to False:

[Popup » auto_dismiss](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.modalview.html#kivy.uix.modalview.ModalView.auto_dismiss)

> ```
> auto_dismiss
> ```
>
> This property determines if the view is automatically dismissed when
>   the user clicks outside it.
>
> auto_dismiss is a BooleanProperty and defaults to True.

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window


Builder.load_string('''
#:kivy 1.11.0

<NumPad>:
    title: "GoTo..."
    size_hint: (0.9, 0.9)
    auto_dismiss: False

<TouchGoToInput>:
    textInput: textInput
    cols: 1
    size: root.size
    pos: root.pos

    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        size_hint_y: .25

        TextInput:
            size_hint_x:1.0
            font_size: self.height - 15
            padding_y: [self.height / 2.0 - (self.line_height / 2.0) * len(self._lines), 0]
            id: textInput
            disabled: True

    GridLayout:
        cols: 3
        Button:
            text: "1"
            on_release: root.addText(self.text)
        Button:
            text: "2"
            on_release: root.addText(self.text)
        Button:
            text: "3"
            on_release: root.addText(self.text)
        Button:
            text: "4"
            on_release: root.addText(self.text)
        Button:
            text: "5"
            on_release: root.addText(self.text)
        Button:
            text: "6"
            on_release: root.addText(self.text)
        Button:
            text: "7"
            on_release: root.addText(self.text)
        Button:
            text: "8"
            on_release: root.addText(self.text)
        Button:
            text: "9"
            on_release: root.addText(self.text)
        Button:
            text: "."
            on_release: root.addText(self.text)
        Button:
            text: "0"
            on_release: root.addText(self.text)
        Button:
            text: "Done"
            on_release: 
                app._popup.dismiss()
''')


class TouchGoToInput(GridLayout):

    def addText(self, text):
        self.textInput.text = self.textInput.text + text


class NumPad(Popup):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(NumPad, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.popupContent = TouchGoToInput()
        self.content = self.popupContent

    def on_open(self):
        # erase previous textInput
        self.popupContent.textInput.text = ''

        # keyboard binding
        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(
            self._keyboard_closed, self, 'text')

        if self._keyboard.widget:
            # If it exists, this widget is a VKeyboard object which you can use
            # to change the keyboard layout.
            pass

        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)

    def _keyboard_closed(self):
        # keyboard have been closed!
        if self._keyboard is not None:
            self._keyboard.unbind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)
            self._keyboard = None

    def _on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        # check for 0...9, or '.' pressed from keyboard
        if (keycode[0] in list(range(48, 58))) or (keycode[0] == 46):
            # keyboard: 0 / 48 to 9 / 57, or decimal / 46
            self.popupContent.addText(text)

        # check for 0...9, or '.' pressed from numpad
        elif (keycode[0] in list(range(256, 267))):
            # numpad0 / 256 to numpad9 / 265, or numpaddecimal / 266
            if keycode[0] == 266:
                self.popupContent.addText('.')
            else:
                self.popupContent.addText(keycode[1][-1:])

        # Keycode is composed of an integer + a string
        # If we hit escape, release the keyboard
        if keycode[1] == 'escape':
            keyboard.release()

        # Return True to accept the key. Otherwise, it will be used by
        # the system.
        return True

    def on_dismiss(self):
        print('\tNumPad.on_dismiss: self.popupContent.textInput.text=', self.popupContent.textInput.text)
        self._keyboard_closed()


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self._popup = NumPad()
        return Button(text="press me", on_press=self._popup.open)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - Numbers and decimal point from Keyboard, NumPad, and Buttons]
[image: Img02 - Button Done clicked]